# validate Date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i need to give user to select a date and a time and get that as an input here i have added the basic code i use and i need to restrict user only to add future date and a time not past dates or time!

```js
 $(function () {
   var currentDate = new Date();
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                //viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    
    
            });
   
   
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT'
            });
   
        });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd"><a style="color:red !important; font-size:18px">* </a>Select a date:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" type='text' class="form-control" min="2015-01-01" required />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Time picker-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd"><a style="color:red !important; font-size:18px ; font-size:18px">* </a>Select a time:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                        <input name="timepicker" id="timepicker" type='text' class="form-control" required />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my question is i need to allow user only to put future date not past ones!

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate options.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

See the official documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max).

Answer (score 1):

or you can check this example from the documentation [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#functions)

```
    $('.starts_on, .ends_on').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });

    $('.starts_on').datetimepicker()
    .on('dp.change', function(v){ 
        var incrementDay = moment(new Date(v.date));
        incrementDay.add(1, 'days');
        $('.ends_on').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(incrementDay);
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });

    $('.ends_on').datetimepicker()
    .on('dp.change', function(v){
        var decrementDay = moment(new Date(v.date));
        decrementDay.subtract(1, 'days');
        $('.starts_on').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(decrementDay);
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });
```

Comment: thank you @eka putra do we need to use moment.js for this?

Comment: not always, you can directly see the documentation [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({
        minDate: 1,
        onSelect: function(theDate) {
            $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(theDate));
        },
       dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use minDate: 1, this should allow only future date

```
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            minDate:1,    
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

i got issue solved by this thank you everyone for your help they were very helpful!

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            //viewMode: 'years',
            //minDate:0, 
            //format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY",minDate: new Date()




        });
```